# How to fix Memory leak in ThreadPoolTaskExecutor in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, memory-leaks, threadpoolexecutor

I am using `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` to execute few operations asynchronously. I am getting the memory leaks as below.

**`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` Configuration**

```
@Bean(name = "specificTaskExecutor")
    public Executor asyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(20);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Seperate");
    TaskDecorator taskDecorator = (Runnable runnable) -> {
        Map<String, String> contextMap = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
        return () -> {
        try {
            MDC.setContextMap(contextMap);
            runnable.run();
        } finally {
            MDC.clear();
        }
        };
    };
    executor.setTaskDecorator(taskDecorator);
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
    }
```

**Async usage:**

```
@Async("specificTaskExecutor")
Public void asyncMethod(){
// some functionality
}
```

**Memory Leaks:**
[image]

[image]

Kindly let me know what I am missing here which causes the memory leak.

Comment: And that is a memory leak because? You are creating 20 threads, max 100. They remain in the pool for some time. So why would this be a memory leak?

Comment: Ok So, can I consider that this will not affect anything in the performance of the application. I just got confused when the MAT tool shows this suspected memory leak.

Comment: Each thread you create will occupy (depending on your OS) around 128kb. You create max 100 (so depending on what you do) you will get 100 * 128kb = ~12.8MB of memory just for having 100 threads. You keep about 130Mb, which is quite a bit more, but that could be related to what tasks you are executing. **pro-tip:** remove the call to `initialize` and change the return type type `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` instead of `Executor`. This will not solve the excessive memory usage but will help in configuration (it will make it proper).

Answer (score 0):

It's important to mention that with no queue capacity being explicity defined in your ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, it leads to infinite queue capacity. Furthermore, the maxPoolSize has no effect, as a new thread will only be created after the queue becomes full.

So, you **must** set the queue capacity to prevent OutOfMemoryErrors.

```
executor.setQueueCapacity(100); // for example
```

As presented in the spring docs: "The main idea is that when a task is submitted, the executor will first try to use a free thread if the number of active threads is currently less than the core size. If the core size has been reached, then the task will be added to the queue as long as its capacity has not yet been reached.

Only then, if the queue’s capacity has been reached, will the executor create a new thread beyond the core size. If the max size has also been reached, then the executor will reject the task.

By default, the queue is unbounded, but this is rarely the desired configuration, because it can lead to OutOfMemoryErrors if enough tasks are added to that queue while all pool threads are busy. Furthermore, if the queue is unbounded, then the max size has no effect at all.

Since the executor will always try the queue before creating a new thread beyond the core size, a queue must have a finite capacity for the thread pool to grow beyond the core size (this is why a fixed size pool is the only sensible case when using an unbounded queue)."

For clarification, here is the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-namespace-executor

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).